# I am a registered sex offender from Arizona. Will I be allowed entry into Scotland?

Tags: uk, scotland, criminal-records, sex-offender

I am traveling to Scotland from Arizona on March 3rd. Will I be allowed to stay in Scotland for vacation until the 12th of March 2024?

Answer (score 7):

A US citizen normally does not need a visa to visit the UK, but those with criminal records do, see [FCDO guidance](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism).

It is unlikely that you will be permitted to enter the UK, especially if you've served time in jail. If you want to try, you'll have to apply for a visa, which can be done at [application page](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa). It is also unlikely that a visa application will be processed in less that 2 months. The typical processing time is 3 weeks, but it can take longer in complex cases such as yours. See
[processing times](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visa-processing-times-applications-outside-the-uk).

The US, UK, Canada, Australia and New Zealand form the [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) intelligence sharing group. The UK **will** know about your record; you won't get in without declaring it.